Cancellative convex spaces and topological vector spaces
I am looking at the definition of convex space here:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/revision/diff/convex+space/38 .
There is a result that links convex spaces to vector (or affine) spaces and I am trying to understand whether it can be extended to topological vector spaces.
This is the result (I am only interested in the case where reals are used for the convex combination). A convex space is cancellative if $y=z$ whenever $c_p(x,y)=c_p(x,z)$ for some $x$ and $p≠0$. A convex space is cancellative if and only if it is isomorphic (as a convex space) to a convex subset of some real vector space.
Given that a topological vector space is a vector space equipped with a topology such that the addition and the scalar multiplication are continuous, I'd like to define a topological convex space to be a convex space equipped with a topology for which the map $c_p(x,y)$ is continuous. Would it be true that a topological convex space is cancellative if and only if it is isomorphic (as a topological convex space) to a convex subset of some real topological vector space?

Just so we're on the same page: are you saying the function from $[0,1] \times C \times C$ to $C$ (with $C$ being our complext space) sending $(p,x,y)$ to $c_p(x,y)$ is required to be continuous?

Right, in the same way one does for the definition of topological vector space for $(x,y) \to x+y$ (meaning that you consider $[0,1] \times C \times C$ to have the product topology, etc...)

Here's a counterexample: let $X$ be the space $\mathbb{R}$, but with the topology containing sets of the form $(r,\infty)$ with $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (as well as the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$), and define the convexity map $f:[0,1] \times X \times X \rightarrow X$ in the usual way. Verifying this to be continuous is non fully trivial, but kind of tedious so I'll leave it to the end.
Now, suppose $X$ was a convex subset of a topological vector space $V$, with $f$ being just the restriction of the natural convexity $f_V$ on $V$. Without loss of generality we can assume $X$ contains the $0$ of $V$, which we can assume is the same as the $0$ in $X$. Next, we can verify that scaling within $X$ is the same as scaling within $V$ ($\cdot_X$ and $\cdot_V$ respectively): we have that, for all $x \in X$, $f(\frac{1}{2},2 \cdot_X x,0) = f_V(\frac{1}{2},2 \cdot_X x, 0) = f_V(\frac{1}{2},2 \cdot_V x,0)$, which means $2 \cdot_X x = 2 \cdot_V x$ by cancelativeness. We can make a similar algument for scaling by $-1$ (using the fact that $f_V(\frac{1}{2},-1 \cdot_X x,x) = f_V(\frac{1}{2},-1 \cdot_V x,x) = 0$), and then extend it to all reals, as all real numbers can be written as $2^n \times (-1)^{\pm 1} \times r$ with $r \in [0,1]$.
Finally, every element of $X$ is of the form $r \cdot_V b$ with some fixed $b \in X - \{0\}$, so $X$ is a vector subspace of $V$, which means without loss of generality, we can assume $V = X$. This is a contradiction, as taking inverses is not continuous in $X$, which completes the proof.
Circling back to verifying that $f$ is continuous: Let $f(p,x,y) = z$ and $z \in (r,\infty)$. Now, I claim there's an $\epsilon$ such that $(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon) \times (x-\frac{z-r}{2},\infty) \times (y-\frac{z-r}{2},\infty)$ maps inside $(r,\infty)$. Taking $\epsilon = \frac{z-r}{2|x-y|}$ should work, unless I bungled something up.
Edit to answer followups:
So, to make notation easier I will introduce the partial function $h:(0,1] \times X \times X \rightarrow X$ as a sort of inverse to our convex function $f$. Specifically, $f(p,x,y) = z$ if and only if $h(p,x,z) = y$. By cancelativeness this is a valid function, but if we assume $X$ to just be a convex subset of a vector space, it doesn't have to be defined everywhere. If it was defined everywhere, we could then construct addition as $a + b = h(\frac{1}{2},0,f(\frac{1}{2},a,b))$, and scaling by $r \in \mathbb{R}$ as
$$r \cdot x = \begin{cases}
    h(\frac{1}{r},0,x) & \textrm{if }r \geq 1 \\
    f(r,0,x) & \textrm{if }r \in [0,1] \\
    h(\frac{1}{2},(-r) \cdot x,0) & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
There is some minor recursion to this definition, but it is well defined. Thus (using the gluing lemma for scaling), we see that if $h$ is continuous, so are addition and scaling (since we already assume $f$ to be continuous). In my counterexample, $h$ is not continuous.
So, what are some minimum assumptions to make $h$ continuous? Well, let's make the idea of $h$ being an inverse of $f$ more precise: from the definition, it seems that $\pi_1 \times \pi_2 \times f:(0,1] \times X \times X \rightarrow (0,1] \times X \times X$ and $\pi_1 \times \pi_2 \times h$ on the same domain and codomain are literally inverses, if $h$ is defined everywhere. If $h$ is not defined everywhere, it is at least always defined on the image of $\pi_1 \times \pi_2 \times f$, so we can just restrict there.
An inverse of a continuous function need not be continuous. Here's my proposal to remedy this: require that $f$ is an open map when restricted to $(0,1] \times X \times X$. After all, addition is an open map in banach spaces by the open mapping theorem (which might even be overkill, since that proves all surjective continuous linear operators are open maps), and scaling by non-zero reals is an open map. So, since $f$ can be constructed from those operations, it should be an open map as well.
This would mean that $h$ is continuous wherever it is defined. I suspect this should be enough to construct an embedding of $X$ in a topological vector space by adding new points wherever $h$ is undefined, and then constructing a topology on that. But, this edit is getting long, so I'll leave that for another time.

Thanks!!! Would it be fair to say that the issue is that the convex structure imposes that the sums are continuous, but not the difference? Also, if additionally I had a distance function $d: C \times C \to \mathbb{R}$ that were continuous, would that be enough?

Also, you are essentially helping me with research... which I'd like to acknowledge when it is published. If you feel up to it, my name is Gabriele Carcassi. I am easy to find... :-)

@Carcassi Thank you, that is very kind of you! You are indeed easy to find, unless there is coincidentally a person with an identical name researching physics. I will write you an e-mail so we can discuss this, as I don't tend to use my real name on public forums.

@Carcassi Also, I'll try to edit my response in a bit to answer your followups.

It did occur to me that requiring the convex combination to be an open map may help, but I am not sure I can justify it from the physics... :-/

@Carcassi There are probably many alternative assumptions you can use, as long as they make $h$ continuous. Maybe some compactness and hausdorffness-like conditions would be probably more physically justifyable (tho, I'm not a physicist, so I'm not sure).
